# How do I extract a substring in InnoSetup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

When writing Pascal scripting code for InnoSetup, how do I extract a substring?

Comment: It depends. You may want to extract file extension, file path, file drive, file name or e.g. relative path. For those situations there is specific set of functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

InnoSetup's [`Copy`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_copy.htm) function can do this.

```
function Copy(S: String; Index, Count: Integer): String;
```

Pascal strings are indexed starting at 1.